# git checkout overload

Tags: git, git-checkout

TL;DR I can't revert a file with git checkout if a branch has the same name.

---

I was working on my GIT repository when found a funny problem.
We've a branch called "build-upload" where we are creating a new "upload" feature.
We also have a file called "bin/build-upload", it's a script than builds the project and uploads it to production.

The thing is I was on the "bin/" directory and modified "build-upload" file and I want to revert it. So I typed

```
git checkout build-upload
```

And the result was

```
amatiasq:~/repo/bin$ git checkout build-upload
M   bin/build-upload
Switched to branch 'build-upload'
```

I didn't pay enought attention to the result, and continued working without realizing I was on another branch. Fortunately before I commit the new changes I saw "bin/build-upload" was modified and this led me to found I switched branch.

The question is. Is there a way to prevent this ambiguity? How can I tell git when I do "checkout" if I want to switch branch or revert a file?

Comment: If it hurts, _Just Don't Do It_. Take care to handle branches and tags as a separate namespace from files (oand from each other).

Comment: Obviously it wasn't intentional, it was an accident I want to know how to face.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to `git help checkout`, everything after a `--` on the command line will be interpreted as a path, not a branch or tag. So, this should probably do what you need:

```
git checkout -- build-upload
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to put a '--' before the path part to eliminate ambiguity with branch names.

```
git checkout <branch> -- <paths..>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do `git checkout ./build-upload` to ensure that `build-upload` is treated as a filename. This is analogous to classic Unix tricks like `rm ./-r` to disambiguate a file named `-r` from the option `-r`.